# what is the right syntax for OrderByDescending with condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to know what is the correct syntax for OrderByDescending with condition

I have the following code,

```
_mobileRepository.GetAllEpisodes().OrderByDescending(x => x.AirDate).ToList();
```

But now, i want to only list AirDate > = 2012, so Could I do the following?

```
_mobileRepository.GetAllEpisodes().OrderByDescending(x => (x.AirDate> 2012)).ToList();
```

what is the correct syntax here?

Comment: Note that you always want to use the Where *before* the OrderBy. That way you're not sorting records that you're then going to throw away.

Comment: @Eric, Really?  While that sounds intuitively correct, it was my understanding that what was being built up was a query expression. As an expression it is not realized until iterated over (such as with a ToList())  If it is in fact one expression, wouldn't they logically do the filter logic of the expression before the sorting?

Comment: @RalphShillington: You are correct that it is a query that is built up. The question then is: how smart is the query execution engine when the query is executed. If it is LINQ to SQL, then the back end database will be extremely smart about doing the filter before the sort. LINQ to Objects isn't nearly that smart; it only performs optimizations on Where and Select. It doesn't optimize Where and OrderBy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter for `AirDate > = 2012` then apply `OrderByDescending`

```
_mobileRepository.GetAllEpisodes().Where(x =>  x.AirDate >= 2012)
                               .OrderByDescending(x => x.AirDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Could I use LINQ notation to do arithmetic? such as Where(( DateTime.Now - x => x.AirDate ).TotalDays <= 365). I don't think this is a legit syntax. what would be a legitimate syntax in this case?

Comment: @doglin something like `Where(x =>  DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.AirDate).TotalDays <= 365 )`

Answer (score 2):

```
_mobileRepository.GetAllEpisodes().Where(x => x.AirDate >= 2012).OrderByDescending(x => x.AirDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

To filter the result, you use `Where` not `OrderByDescending`:

```
_mobileRepository.GetAllEpisodes()
  .Where(x => x.AirDate >= 2012)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.AirDate)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter data you can use [the `Where` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx):

```
mobileRepository.GetAllEpisodes()
   .Where(x=>x.AirDate > 2012)
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.AirDate).ToList();
```